# Error: Unable to resolve module `./index` from `\node_modules\react-native\scripts/.`

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am getting this error when upgrade my react native.

It says

> Error: Unable to resolve module `./index` from
>   `\node_modules\react-native\scripts/.`: The module `./index` could not
>   be found from `\node_modules\react-native\scripts/.`. Indeed, none of
>   these files exist:

Actually don't know how to solve. Can anyone help please. Thanks

The version I am currently using

"react": "^16.8.4",
"react-native": "^0.59.0",

Comment: Here is how to fix it [Fix for **Can't find module ./index in react native**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55318326/react-native-cant-find-module-index-on-fresh-initialized-app)

Comment: It works fine. You are a life saver. Thank you so so much... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This linked solved my problem.](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/23908#issuecomment-475921607)

Though you will need to do this for every time you start a new project.. its an upgrade issue from react-native

Update node_modules\react-native\scripts\launchPackager.bat file.
    @echo off
    title Metro Bundler
    call .packager.bat

```
// delete this line
node "%~dp0..\cli.js" start 

Add this line
node "%~dp0..\cli.js" start --projectRoot ../../../ 

pause
exit
```

We are giving project root path to Metro instance here,

Or in \node_modules@react-native-community\cli\build\commands\runAndroid\runAndroid.js edit this,
    const procConfig = {

```
    // delete this line    
    cwd: scriptsDir

    // add this line
    cwd: process.cwd()
};
```

Comment: in my case, i noticed it after an upgrade, in my react-native....with cwd:process.cwd() in my runAdriod.js file

Answer (score 0):

Try removing everything from `node_modules` and then do `npm install`

```
cd node_modules
rm -rf *

cd ../
npm install
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. I have clear the cache But no luck.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue in the latest upgrade of react-native version. Please downgrade your current it will work. I tried the same

Answer (score 0):

Same exact problem I am facing too. I just updated to 0.59.1 and this isn't working...
As a work around, I am running the metro builder in a separate tab, and then running react in a separate tab.

`react-native start --reset-cache` in one terminal and left it open
`react-native run-android` in another terminal