# React Native can't find module ./index on fresh initialized app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I issued `react-native init MyApp` and `react-native run-android`

Metro server started but when phone request data from it, it crashed giving

```
Error: Unable to resolve module `./index` from `\node_modules\react-native\scripts/.`: The module `./index` could not be found from `\node_modules\react-native\scripts/.`. Indeed, none of these files exist:
```

Machine has newly installed node, npm and it's modules so no cache issues, but then what is preventing react native to give even its first glimpse?

Comment: try to run `.\adb reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081`

Comment: ok, Good work :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution** [Github Ref: #23908 (comment)](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/23908#issuecomment-475889443)

Metro server instance is started by `runAndroid.js` from `@react-native-community` module if asked for `react-native run-android`

Problem is with **Working Directory**, Metro instance is launched with wrong working directory and no `projectRoot` is passed in `launchPackager.bat`

Threre are two fixes for this issue, apply only one of the below

**Update `node_modules\react-native\scripts\launchPackager.bat file`.**

```
@echo off
title Metro Bundler
call .packager.bat

:: delete this line
node "%~dp0..\cli.js" start 

:: Add this line
node "%~dp0..\cli.js" start --projectRoot ../../../ 

pause
exit
```

We are giving project root path to Metro instance here via `projectRoot` argument,

**Or in `\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\commands\runAndroid\runAndroid.js` edit this**,

```
const procConfig = {

    // delete this line    
    cwd: scriptsDir

    // add this line
    cwd: process.cwd()

};
```

We are launching Metro Server with working directory to our project root

For more info see `startServerInNewWindow()` function in `\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\commands\runAndroid\ranAndroid.js`, it is passing `react-native` directory rather than **project root** in third argument of `spawn()`.

It worked, hope this will help you as well

Comment: It already has helped many people on github, https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/23908#issuecomment-475889443